# App crashing upon calling server function

Tags: android

Trying to run local server from inside an android app, but the app keep trashing the time the button is clicked to run the server, my code is:

```kotlin
package tk.android

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text).text = stringFromJNI()
         btn.setOnClickListener {
            txt.setText(reverse(txt.text.toString()))
            server()
        }

    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    external fun stringFromJNI(): String
    external fun server() : Void // extern void server(); // Here is the server
    private external fun reverse(str: String): String // extern char* reverse(char* in)

    companion object {
        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

The android app is built with Native where 3 functions are defined, 2 of then running smoothly, but the one related to the server is crasking.

My native functions are defined as:

```cpp
// file cpp/native-lib.cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#include "libfoo.h" // our library header

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_tk_android_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

extern "C" {
    jstring
    Java_tk_android_MainActivity_reverse(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jstring str) {
        // Reverse text here 
        const char* cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, 0);
        char* cout = reverse(const_cast<char*>(cstr));
        jstring out = env->NewStringUTF(cout);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, cstr);
        free(cout);
        return out;
    }
}

extern "C" {
    void
    Java_tk_android_MainActivity_server() {
        // Nothing here, as it is void input and void output
        server();
    }
}
```

With the CMake file defined as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project("android")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

add_library(lib_foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib_foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_NO_SONAME 1)
set_target_properties(lib_foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libfoo.so)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       lib_foo

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

The server file I'm running is simple one built with GO, and compiled as shared library

```golang
package main

import "C"

// other imports should be seperate from the special Cgo import
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

//export reverse
func reverse(in *C.char) *C.char {
    return C.CString(foo.Reverse(C.GoString(in)))
}

//export server
func server() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func Reverse(in string) string {
    n := 0
    rune := make([]rune, len(in))
    for _, r := range in {
        rune[n] = r
        n++
    }
    rune = rune[0:n]
    for i := 0; i < n/2; i++ {
        rune[i], rune[n-1-i] = rune[n-1-i], rune[i]
    }
    return string(rune)
}

func main() {}
```

Compiled to Android with the below Make file:

```
//file: Makefile
ANDROID_OUT=../myApp/app/src/main/jniLibs
ANDROID_SDK=$(HOME)/Library/Android/sdk
NDK_BIN=$(ANDROID_SDK)/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin

android-armv7a:
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOOS=android \
    GOARCH=arm \
    GOARM=7 \
    CC=$(NDK_BIN)/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang \
    go build -buildmode=c-shared -o $(ANDROID_OUT)/armeabi-v7a/libfoo.so ./cmd/libfoo

android-arm64:
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOOS=android \
    GOARCH=arm64 \
    CC=$(NDK_BIN)/aarch64-linux-android21-clang \
    go build -buildmode=c-shared -o $(ANDROID_OUT)/arm64-v8a/libfoo.so ./cmd/libfoo

android-x86:
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOOS=android \
    GOARCH=386 \
    CC=$(NDK_BIN)/i686-linux-android21-clang \
    go build -buildmode=c-shared -o $(ANDROID_OUT)/x86/libfoo.so ./cmd/libfoo

android-x86_64:
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOOS=android \
    GOARCH=amd64 \
    CC=$(NDK_BIN)/x86_64-linux-android21-clang \
    go build -buildmode=c-shared -o $(ANDROID_OUT)/x86_64/libfoo.so ./cmd/libfoo

android: android-armv7a android-arm64 android-x86 android-x86_64
```

I do not know if there is something wrong in the definision of `Java_tk_android_MainActivity_server()` or it is crashing because the server will be listening to http signal!

[image]

I got the follwoing only once the app crash:

> I/chatty: uid=10104(tk.android) Thread-2 identical 1 line
> W/tk.android: Accessing hidden method
> Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->yieldIfContendedHelper(ZJ)Z
> (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stacktrace

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I got `I/chatty: uid=10104(tk.android) Thread-2 identical 1 line
W/tk.android: Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->yieldIfContendedHelper(ZJ)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)`

Comment: `I` is "info". And `W` is "warning". Neither of these are errors. You will need to dig deeper into the logcat to find the error from the crash.

Comment: I had a similar issue. It was fixed by replacing NDK toolchain from 21.0.6113669 to 25.1.8937393.  Still have no idea about the root cause :(